# Omnifaces 1.6.2 and Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, jsf, cdi, omnifaces

I'm currently using Primefaces 4.0, Omnifaces 1.6.2, MyFaces 2.1.12, and Google App Engine 1.8.3.

When deploying the application I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.naming.InitialContext is a restricted class. Please see the Google  App Engine developer's guide for more details.
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.reject(Runtime.java:51)
    at org.omnifaces.util.JNDI.lookup(JNDI.java:82)
    at org.omnifaces.config.BeanManager.init(BeanManager.java:68)
    at org.omnifaces.config.BeanManager.getReference(BeanManager.java:107)
    at org.omnifaces.application.OmniApplication.createConverter(OmniApplication.java:86)
    at org.primefaces.config.ConfigContainer.initConfig(ConfigContainer.java:69)
    at org.primefaces.config.ConfigContainer.<init>(ConfigContainer.java:59)
```

Is it possible to **disable CDI features/JNDI lookups in Omnifaces** at startup?

I didn't have that problem in Omnifaces 1.6.0.

Thanks in advance,

Rafael.

Comment: Geez. Looking into it.

Comment: Please try 1.6.3 snapshot: https://code.google.com/p/omnifaces/issues/detail?id=263

Comment: Thank you very much BalusC.
I tried the 1.6.3 snapshot and now it is working as expected.

Comment: Superb. I'll release 1.6.3 soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem has been fixed in [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) 1.6.3. The solution was to fail fast and silently when JNDI (and CDI) aren't available in the runtime classpath.

```
try {
    Class.forName("javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager"); // Is CDI present?
    Class.forName("javax.naming.InitialContext"); // Is JNDI present? (not on Google App Engine)
}
catch (Throwable ignore) {
    return; // CDI or JNDI not supported on this environment.
}

// ...
```